# How to set up Clean url for Drupal with Nginx in localhost

Tags: php, drupal, nginx, drupal-7, clean-urls

I setup a nginx server in my localhost
So now I want to enable clean url for this server

(Change localhost/drupalsite/?q=abc to localhost/drupalsite/abc)

I have tried some tutorials but thet don't work for me

```
http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal
https://drupal.org/node/976392
http://richardbanks.net/blog/2012/11/nginx-url-rewrites-the-correct-method
```

This is some basic config in nginx.conf file

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /srv/nginx/www/nginx_htdocs/;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /srv/nginx/www/nginx_htdocs/;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/nginx/www/nginx_htdocs/$fastcgi_script_name;

            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        #--------------- TUNG CUSTOM





        #------------- END CUSTOM

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a gist](http://gist.github.com/Mulkave/6103129) of a full configuration that works very well with Drupal's clean URL's

Answer (score 1):

You must try to handle not found urls as possible query strings for index.php (if that's how Drupal works, which I'm not sure).

For example, in your first location block:

```
location / {
       root   /srv/nginx/www/nginx_htdocs/;
       index  index.html index.htm index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
    }
```

This way, if

```
`http://mysite.com/xyz`
```

doesn't match any file or folder, it gets handed to index.php in the form of

```
`http://mysite.com/index.php?xyz`
```